# Facebook graph api search displaying users in Facebook but not in graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, search

Im using facebook graph api in my hybrid app. I recently came across a bug or undocumented feature. If i search for a user that i dont have any relations with, the response returns blank: (data: Array[0]). I knew this person had a facebook acoount, so i went to facebook.com and searched for the person normally, which worked (The person exists on facebook).

Is there some restriction on the search or something? As of what i have seen in the docs, there is nothing that describes this "restriction". Thanks!

The name is also consists of three words. Tried a b c, a+b+c and a-b-c. Still no result.